# Restrict table data 'contenteditable' attribute to only Integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below code allows me to edit the table data row but may i know how can i restrict it to only integers.

Thank you in advance for your time :)

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="product_rate"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try reading the keyCode of the onkeypress event, determining whether it is a number (0-9) or not and then returning true or false respectively

```
<td onkeypress = "return testCharacter(event);" contenteditable="true" class="product_rate"></td>

function testCharacter(event) {
  if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || event.keyCode === 13) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Oh, and if you wish to allow negative values then you must include the keyCode for the - sign which (i guess) is 45 :)

Comment: thank you so much for the answer ! it works but can you explain what are this numbers 48,57, 13

Answer (score 1):

if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || event.keyCode === 13)

those numbers are the assci code in decimal:
https://www.ascii-code.com/

48 is for the **0**; 57 is for the **9**; 45 is for the **-**